# Virtual Com Port Driver Wouldn't Install on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers

My software requires a user to supply Admin's credentials when asked by windows operating system.

This scenario used to be working well with Windows-7 where user would double click on the executable and Windows will prompt a dialog asking the user to supply Admin credentials.

With Windows-10, I am observing that if I log in as Admin, I am able to install Virtual Com Port Driver X64 (VCP_V1.3.1_Setup.exe) prerequisite as well as able to install software too but with other non-admin accounts where I am supposed to supply Admin Credentials, software install seems to be hung while installing Virtual Com Port Driver x64.

Comment: You need to run the executable as another user if you want to install it with your current Windows 10 configuration.  Windows 7 worked slightly different when allowing additional privileges to a process.

Comment: I am sorry but I may not have understood the comment. I am running the executable as another user I think that is why windows prompting a dialog to me to supply Admin credentials, I have to provide different domain to along with my user name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research it was found out that there is no need to install Virtual Com Port Driver(VCP_V1.3.1_Setup.exe) in windows 10 as usage of the native Inbox driver is recommended, for more information, read their technical documentation at https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-stm32102.html.

> Compatible with the x86 and x64 platforms
>
> The STSW-STM32102 software package contains four installation files
>   based on the various versions of the Microsoft® operating system.
>
> OS versions prior to Windows® 7 are compatible with the Windows® 7
>   installations included in the package.
>
> Starting from Windows® 10, the STSW-STM32102 driver is no more
>   adequate and the usage of the native inbox driver is recommended.

Comment: You should quote the relevant information from your link in the event of the link no longer working.

Comment: Sure, will do .